# From where and how can I solve problem with unexpected name in Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor

How to solve [Markup element with unexpected name 'NavLink'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbFbz.png)

That problem I noticed today from where I don't know.

Comment: What happens if you change `NavLink to nav`? Only for the Html Tag.

Comment: Post the code text, not the image.

Comment: @panoskarajohn with 'nav' razor page dosen't show any error but I still have it in another razor files [here](http://prntscr.com/qafey3) it seems that I don't have any package

Comment: Yes i would go with the answer. Seems your .net version is outdated. so it does not recognize the Component.

Comment: Try to delete obj and bin folder and rebuild

Answer (score 1):

You likely have an out dated version of Visual Studio.

Please make sure you have:

- Visual Studio **Preview**
- Version 16.5.0 Preview 1.0
- .NET Core 3.1 SDK.
- Install the .NET Core 3.1 or later (Preview) SDK. (for WebAssembly projects)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/get-started?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: `C:\>dotnet --info
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   3.1.100`
I have checked, also I opened an old project and there I don't have any problem.

Comment: What VS do you have?

Comment: had Version 16.4.1, updated to Version 16.5.0 Preview 1.0 the problem still persist

Answer (score 1):

The same problem happened to me. There was this error, but the project could be generated and displayed through IIS Express.
I solved the thing by shutting VS down, deleting the .vs directory in the project directory, then restarting.